# Adding movie clips into 2D array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, 2d

```
package 
{

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

// class 
public class GameGrid extends MovieClip
{
    private var gameHeight:Number = 600;
    private var gameWeight:Number = 800;
    private var gridHeight:Number = 50;
    private var gridWeight:Number = 50;
    private var rowNumber:int = 12;
    private var columnNumber:int = 16;
    private var backgroundGrid:Array = new Array(12,16);
    private var foregroundGrid:Array = new Array(12,16);

    function GameGrid(){

    }

    function addBackGrid(rowN:int,colN:int,mcObject:MovieClip)
    {
        backgroundGrid[rowN,colN].push(mcObject);
    }

    function addForeGrid(rowN:int,colN:int,mcObject:MovieClip)
    {
        foregroundGrid[rowN,colN].push(mcObject);
    }

    function calculateRowDiff(rowA:int,rowB:int):Number
    {
        return Math.abs(rowA-rowB);
    }
    function calculateColDiff(colA:int,colB:int):Number
    {
        return Math.abs(colA-colB);
    }
    function calculateCorDiff(colA:int,colB:int,rowA:int,rowB:int):Number
    {
        return Math.sqrt((calculateRowDiff(rowA,rowB) * calculateRowDiff(rowA,rowB)) + (calculateColDiff(colA,colB) * calculateColDiff(colA,colB)));
    }
    // add to stage
    function paintbackgroundGrid()
    {
        for (var i:int=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            for (var j:int=0; j<12; j++)
            {
                MovieClip(backgroundGrid[i,j]).x = i * 50;
                MovieClip(backgroundGrid[i,j]).y = j * 50;
                stage.addChild(MovieClip(backgroundGrid[i,j]));
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

So what this GameGrid class do is to hold an Array of grids(or tiles which extends MovieCLip) that will be added to the main stage and will call the initializeItem function.

```
function InitializeItem(e:Event)
    {
        var gamemap = new GameGrid();
        var mc:MovieClip = new MainCharacter();
        gamemap.addBackGrid(1,1,mc);
        gamemap.paintbackgroundGrid();
        //trace("Year: "+gameTime.gameYear+" Month: "+gameTime.gameMonth+" Day: "+gameTime.gameDay+"  "+gameTime.gameHour+":"+gameTime.gameMinute+":"+gameTime.gameSecond);

    }
```

The initializeItem should create an instance of gamegrid, and add movieclips to their respective locations(stored using array) and display them.
and this is the error stacktrace:

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 1 not found on Number and there is no default value.
    at GameGrid/addBackGrid()

The debugger suggest that the error came from the line  backgroundGrid[rowN,colN].push(mcObject);
Is there a way I can hold a 2d array movieclips? I'm new to AS3 and it looks very similar to JAVA, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private var backgroundGrid = [];

function addBackGrid(rowN:int,colN:int,mcObject:MovieClip) {

    if (backgroundGrid[rowN] == null) {

         backgroundGrid[rowN] = [];

    }

    backgroundGrid[rowN][colN] = mcObject;
}
```

In as3, following code means create a array and the array contains two elements, one is 12, and the other is 16.

```
 private var backgroundGrid:Array = new Array(12,16);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, though it requires me to make another function to manually "initialize" all the 16 rows and 12 columns to null.